# Why can't I pass these two lists into a recursive function in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to write a simpler parser in OCaml but I have run into a problem I can't get past.  I have simplified the code to a bare minimum example, which gives me the same error:

I want to write a function in OCaml that takes in a list of integers and outputs a list of strings.
The rules are that if there are two `1`s in a row then it outputs `"eleven"`, if there is only one `1` it outputs `"one"`
and for any other number it outputs `"other"`. This python code does the job:

```py
def convert(numbers, names):
    if len(numbers) == 0:
      return names
    n = numbers.pop(0)
    if n == 1:
        if len(numbers) > 0 and numbers[0] == 1:
            numbers.pop(0)
            names.append("eleven")
        else:
            names.append("one")
    else:
        names.append("other")
    return convert(numbers, names)

convert([1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1], [])
# -> ['eleven', 'other', 'one', 'other', 'one']
```

My attempt in OCaml is this:

```ml
let rec convert (numbers : int list) (names : string list) = function
  | [] -> List.rev names
  | 1 :: 1 :: t -> convert t ("eleven" :: names)
  | 1 :: t -> convert t ("one" :: names)
  | _ :: t -> convert t ("other" :: names)
;;

convert [1; 1; 2; 3] [];;
```

What I think will happen is `convert` will call itself recursively: the list of integers will be get smaller and the list
of strings bigger until there are no more integers left:

```
convert [1; 1; 2; 1; 3; 1] []
-> convert [2; 1; 3; 1] ["eleven"]
  -> convert [1; 3; 1] ["other"; "eleven"]
    -> convert [3; 1] ["one"; "other"; "eleven"]
      -> convert [1] ["other"; "one"; "other"; "eleven"]
        -> convert [] ["one"; "other"; "one"; "other"; "eleven"]
          -> ["eleven"; "other"; "one"; "other"; "one"]
```

But what actually happens is a compilation error:

```
Error: This expression has type int list -> string list
       but an expression was expected of type string list
```

highlighting the text `convert t ("eleven" :: names)`

What's going on here? I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`function | ...` is actually short-hand for `fun x -> match x with | ...`. That is:

```
let convert numbers names = function
  | ...
```

is equivalent to

```
let convert numbers names something_else =
  match something_else with
  | ...
```

Your `convert` function therefore expects three arguments, and `convert t ("eleven" :: names)` returns a function `int list -> string list` rather than just a `string list` as inferred from the first branch.

Replace `function` with `match numbers with` to have it compile:

```
let rec convert (numbers : int list) (names : string list) =
  match numbers with
  | [] -> List.rev names
  | 1 :: 1 :: t -> convert t ("eleven" :: names)
  | 1 :: t -> convert t ("one" :: names)
  | _ :: t -> convert t ("other" :: names)
;;

convert [1; 1; 2; 3] [];;
```

Comment: Or simply remove `numbers` from the original code and call `convert [] [1; 1; 2; 3]`. By having the input last you can also make names an optional argument defaulting to [], meaning you could just call `convert [1; 1; 2; 3]` and it would do the right thing.